# How to ignore useEffect do any actions if some properties changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to ignore useEffect do any actions if 'roomCounts' changes in 'filterParams'. Any ideas?

```
filterParams: {
    blockIds: [],
    roomCounts: [],
    pageNo: 1,
    pageSize: 1000,
    realEstateUUIDs: [],
    cityUUID: '',
    priceInMillionMax: null,
    priceInMillionMin: null,
    ready: null,
  },


  const filterParams = useSelector((state) => state.user.filterParams);
  const isFirstLoad = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstLoad.current) {
      dispatch(getBuildingList()).then(() => {
        dispatch(setBuildingID(null));
        dispatch(setApartmentList([]));
      });
    }
  }, [filterParams]);
```

Comment: Apply whatever logic you need to determine that `filterParams.roomCounts` has changed in the condition for whatever the `useEffect` callback is doing.

Comment: @DrewReese I would do that but I have no idea how to exclude filterParams.roomCounts in useEffect

Comment: Are you just needing to compare `filterParams.roomCounts` of the current render cycle from the previous render cycle? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Comment: Instead of passing `filterParams` into `useEffect`, you can pass each individual elements like `filterParams.blockIds, filterParams.pageNo, ...`

Answer (score 0):

you could do like

```
useEffect(() => {
// actions when value changes
},[formParams.blockIds,formParams.ready])
```

which will listen to the value change and trigger action inside the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing filterParams into useEffect, you can pass each individual elements like filterParams.blockIds, filterParams.pageNo,

```
 useEffect(() => {// actions values chnage}, 
 [formParams.blockIds,fromParams.pageNo,formParams.ready])
```

I think you need to pass the specific value rather than the whole object